# Ubuntu 14.04 - Uninstall manually installed NVIDIA driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, uninstall, nvidia-graphics-card

first of all: Im new to linux:)
I would like to reinstall my nvidia driver. Therefore, I'd like to uninstall my currently installed driver first (version: 346).

I already purged all nvidia files with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get -s purge 'nvidia-*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

However, when I checked sysinfo, it said that the nvidia driver 346 is still installed. I heard that purging is the wrong method for manually installed drivers, but before I change my kernel or whatever I wanted to make sure that I do the right thing.

So can you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

To remove purged packages run this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I installed nvidia drivers on an install of (a) ubuntu14.04(-based OS) and i succeeded. I can probably help you with succesfully installing the drivers again if you want to.